# Python ctypes: How to call a function which should return an array of strings?

Tags: python, c++, arrays, string, ctypes

I need to create a c-function, which should be called from Python - using ctypes - and which should provide an array of strings to the calling python function. I have full control of both environments.

Preferably, it should work with Python 2 and 3.

I have this c-function:

```
long ProvideTexts(wchar_t** texts, long textCount, long stringMaxSize)
```

the return value is an error code. texts is the actual array. textCount is the number of elements in the array. stringMaxSize is the maximum size of each string.

I am trying to allocate everything in Python and to have the c++ function overwrite the strings. I am not sure if this is the best way. I figured it was the simplest way to go since the memory will need to be de-allocated in Python.

This is my (non-working) code to create the strings and call the function:

```
import ctypes
stringMaxSize = 1000
ProvideTextsMethod = loadedDll.ProvideTexts
ProvideTextsMethod.restype = ctypes.c_long
arrayType = ctypes.c_wchar_p * textCount
pyArray = arrayType()
for i in range(0, textCount):
    pyArray[i] = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(stringMaxSize) # fails here
ProvideTextsMethod.argtypes = [arrayType, ctypes.c_long, ctypes.c_long]
errorCode = ProvideTextsMethod(pyArray, textCount, stringMaxSize)
```

I get this error:

incompatible types, c_wchar_Array_1000 instance instead of c_wchar_p instance

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to cast it since pyArray is an array of c_whar_p:

```
for i in range(0, textCount):
    pyArray[i] = ctypes.cast(ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(stringMaxSize), ctypes.c_wchar_p)
```

Does this help?

Comment: Yes. Works like a charm. I had actually reached the same conclusion myself, but was only able to test it now.